# trying to install 13.10 on Hipstreet Equinox2 tablet

Tags: ubuntu-touch, 13.10, tablet

Not sure how to install on tablets I'm 13.10 on desktop so do I download a different ver for tablets

Answer (score 0):

Installing Ubuntu touch on tablets should be the same as phones. Try [This](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/install)
.